# Custom form validation class

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I created My_Form_validation class that extends from CI_Form_validation class.

I created a custom method to validate alpha strings with withe spaces, and work properly. But, now i need validate if an id exists in the database.

So i created a method in My_Form_validation to check it, but not work, the validation always return false:

**My_Form_validation**

```
class My_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function get_error_array(){
        return $this->_error_array;
    }

    public function alpha_space($value){
        $str = str_replace(" ", "", $value);
        return ctype_alpha($str);
    }

    public function entity_exist($id){
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Validation rule**

```
'entity_report' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'id',
        'label' => 'id',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|is_natural_no_zero|entity_exist'
    )
)
```

Why Codeigniter not catch the validator from the validation class ? I dont want the validator method in a controller.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with that you not make instance of `CI`

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
 // reference to the CodeIgniter super object
$this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

And set your validation rules like

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'The %s is not valid.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Use like this

    create form_validation.php file in config folder.


     $config = array(
    'entity_report' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'id',
            'label' => 'ID',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[2]'
        )
    )
);

    insert this line in autoload.php
    $autoload['config'] = array('form_validation');

    if ($this->form_validation->run('entity_report') == FALSE) {
       Your code here.
    } else { 
     your code here. 
    }
```